# How do I remove an element from an array in Java? And how do I skip null array elements?

Tags: java, arrays, null

I'm working through a class assignment and I'm not sure how to remove an element from an array. I've read suggestions to use ArrayUtils or convert the array to a linked list. I'm still very new to Java, so I'm not sure if I actually need to do something like this or if I'm overlooking something that's much simpler. I also need to complete a couple of processes that require skipping all null elements in the array. I don't have a great professor and communication attempts are futile, so I'm hoping someone here can help. My code follows. The relevant bits begin at "public void remove". I'm just posting all of the code in this class to give a fuller picture of what's going on:

```
public class WatchCollection
{   

private Watch watches[];    // an array of references to Watch objects
                            // watches[i] == null if there is no watch in position i
private int num;            // size of the array

private void init(int numberOfWatches) {
    watches = new Watch[numberOfWatches];
    for (int i=0;i<numberOfWatches;++i)
    {
        watches[i] = null;
    }
    num = numberOfWatches;
}
public WatchCollection(int numberOfWatches)
{   
    init(numberOfWatches);
}
public WatchCollection (Watch  w1)
{
    init(1);
    add(w1);            
}

// TODO Define WatchCollection (Watch w1, Watch w2) constructor
public WatchCollection (Watch w1, Watch w2)
{
}

// TODO Define WatchCollection (Watch w1, Watch w2, Watch w3) constructor
public WatchCollection (Watch w1, Watch w2, Watch w3)
{
}

public void add    ( Watch w )
{
    for(int i=0;i<num;++i)
    {
        if (watches[i]==null)
        {
            watches[i]=w;
            return;
        }
    }
}
public void remove ( Watch w )
{
    // TODO Write a code that removes Watch w if it is in the array

}

public int size()
{
    // TODO Write a code that returns actual number of watches, skip all null array elements
}

public Watch at( int index)
{
    // TODO Write a code that returns a watch with the specified index (skip all null array elements)
    // TODO Throw an exception if the index is < 0 or >= actual number of watches
    // For example, if the array contains w1 w2 null w3 w4
    // index 0 -> w1
    // index 1 -> w2
    // index 2 -> w3
    // index 3 -> w4
    // index 4 -> an exception

}

public String toString()
{
    String str="{\n";

    int index=0;
    for(int i=0;i<num;++i)
    {
        if (watches[i]!=null)
        {
            str+=" " +index++ + ": " +watches[i] + "\n";
        }
    }
    str+=" }";
    return str;      
 }
}
```

Comment: Just use an `ArrayList` and make your life easier

Comment: It seems you are asking us to do your homework for you. What have *you* done?

Comment: Arrays are full of `null` when you create them.  You don't need to null them out before using them.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` is a builtin class that offers indexed access to elements, the ability to remove arbitrary elements, and dynamic expansion.

Comment: +1 if you cannot use this class because it's an exercise, the OP should at least read this class and copy what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a class assignment, I'll just provide the algorithm to implement a remove method in your array (assuming this is an algorithm course):

```
function remove (Element element)
    int index <- -1
    for i <- 0 to num - 1
        if (array[i] is equals to element) then
            index <- i
            break
        end if
    end for
    if index > -1 then
        for i <- index to num - 2
            array[i] <- array[i+1]
        end for
        num <- num - 1
    end if
end function
```

If this is an exercise about Java programming, it would be better to declare an `ArrayList` and use it since it already implements all these methods for you.

Comment: You could just given the OP the code from ArrayList which is not cheating too much I think. ;)  Silly question, why are there two loops and not one?

Comment: @PeterLawrey since is a class assignment, I prefer to not give the straight implementation :).

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know, but since it is a class assignment, I guess the teacher want to test the students capacity to implement this by themselves. I don't take this as a Java programming course (otherwise it would be better using `ArrayList` from the beginning), instead an algorithm course (which will make sense).

Answer (score 1):

Without giving you the answer, here is how you could improve when you have.

```
public class WatchCollection {
    private Watch watches[];    // an array of references to Watch objects
    // watches[i] == null if there is no watch in position i
    private int num = 0;        // size of the array used.

    public WatchCollection(int numberOfWatches) {
        watches = new Watch[numberOfWatches];
    }

    public WatchCollection(Watch w1) {
        this(1);
        add(w1);
    }

    public void add(Watch w) {
        if (watches.length == num + 1)
            watches = Arrays.copyOf(watches, num*2);
        watches[num++] = w;
    }
```

You should try to keep your solution as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here All you want is dealing with a Watch objects, so you don't need to use array.

Using [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

is the best way to do your work.

This class has methods for accessing indexed elements, removing indexed element, dynamic expansion of the array etc.

The link leads to the official documentation for the ArrayList class.

Answer (score 0):

Use Arraylist instead of array. if you already have an array, convert that to A